# Strange recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve $f(n)=f( \sqrt{n}$) .Seems very strange to me, the iterator (iterator means how many steps we need to take in order to reach 1 ) then the steps are  indeed $\lg\lg(n$) but how should I proceed? I found the answer it is $f(n)$=$\Theta(\lg\lg(n))$,but why?

Comment: What is '$lglgn$'? And what is $\theta$?

Comment: log2(log2(n)) and big theta of 1 (big theta is used in programming)

Comment: $f(n)=f(n^{1/2})=f(n^{1/4})=\cdots=f(n^{1/2^k})$

Comment: Do we know that $f$ is continous or not?

Comment: Yes continuous and positive

Comment: Probably better to use $\Theta$ (`\Theta`) instead of $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** [Master's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). ${     }$